# Unavailable to install Tensorflow 1.x on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I have a reason that I should use Tensorflow 1.x release, but it returns an error with message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.2 (from versions: 2.2.0.rc1 ~~~~~
ERROR: No matching disribution found for tensorflow==1.15.2
```

[image]

I also tried .whl installation but the latest Tensorflow 1.15.2 support cp37 which I can't use it anymore.

Is tensorflow 1.x is no longer supported on pip or pypi? Or should I downgrade python(3.8 > 3.7) and install Tensorflow using .whl file?

[System Environment]
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Python version : 3.8.2
pip version : 20.0.2

Thanks.

Comment: Tensorflow versions earlier that 2.2 do not support Python 3.8. If you want to use Tensorflow 1.15 you will need to downgrade.

Answer (score 7):

---

According to tensorflow installation guide tensorflow is available on Python 3.5–3.7 you are using a newer version of Python.

---

### **The answer above is outdated**

Tensorflow supports **Python 3.8** now, but **Python 3.8** support requires

- **TensorFlow 2.2** or later
- **pip 19.0** or later
- **Ubuntu 16.04** or later
- **macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra)** or later
- **Windows 7** or later
- **Raspbian 9.0** or later

Also **GPU** support requires a **CUDA-enabled card** (Ubuntu and Windows)

You can check your Python and pip version with these commands:

```
python --version | python3 --version
Out: Python 3.8.2

pip --version | pip3 --version
Out: pip 20.1.1
```

You can upgrade your pip with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

More info can be found on this link: [Install TensorFlow with pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just downgrade python version, right?

Comment: Yeap just downgrade it, your system fulfilling the other requriements such as "pip 19.0 or later" and "Ubuntu 16.04 or later (64-bit)"

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer :D Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend that you avoid installing third-party Python libraries system-wide using `pip` that will then rely on your system Python. You also really don't want to avoid manually upgrading/downgrading your system Python.

I prefer to use [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) to install TensorFlow. [Instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html) for installing Conda on Linux are pretty straightforward.

Once you have installed Conda you can install TensorFlow 1.15 with a single command.

```
conda create --name tensorflow-15 \
    tensorflow-gpu=1.15 \
    cudatoolkit=10.1 \
    cudnn=7.6 \
    nccl=2.4 \ # only relevant if you have more than one GPU
    python=3.6 \
    pip=20.0
```

One of the many things I like about Conda is that it provides a single tool to manage environments and packages within a particular environment. It also has a much gentler learning curve compared with other tools for isolating software environments like Docker.

If you are interested in learning more about Conda, then you can check out these teaching materials that I am developing.

https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/introduction-to-conda-for-data-scientists/

Comment: Try tensorflow-gpu=1.15 not  tensorflow_gpu=1.15; the marching rules for package names are very strict.

Answer (score 3):

Seems more and more we have to switch to using containers (Docker, and probably cloud VMs), because everything is incompatible with everything. Yes, you can start a Docker container running Python 3.7 and Tensorflow 1.x, on any version of Linux, but then you want to load files from that container, you have to pass black-magic command line options to mount volumes. Tried using Tensorflow 2 and everything fails. No more tf.Session(), no more tf.global_variables_initializer(), etc. So no working Tensorflow in Ubuntu, you have to use Docker.

Comment: Docker "black magic" not required! Check out my answer above using Conda.

Comment: If adding a couple of parameters to the docker command is "Black Magic", what is Conda itself and its underlying engine, the _Bible of Vodoo_? Running a well suited container it's always preferable than installing a thousand things under the hood that "just works" and you have the extra perks of learning something and knowing what the heck you are actually doing

Comment: Using docker can be a great answer to solve this problem! Thanks and sorry for late reply. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate your dependencies by using Docker or conda environments, I used:

```
conda create -n new_env  python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu=1.2.1 anaconda
```

and works fine:)